# how do I perform spreadsheet type calculations in R?

Tags: r, loops, spreadsheet, iteration

I want to perform a calculation in R that would be simple in Excel.  Let's say I have a long column of number and I want to subtract row 1 from row 2, and row 3 from row 4, and so on, so that they I am subtracting subsequent pairs of numbers.  How do I do this?

Or even something simpler.  How do I subtract row 1 from row 2, and then row 2 from row 3, and so on? Basically here I'm finding the difference between each two rows.

This should be very easy, but I've spent a few hours trying things and searching for answers to no avail.

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the function `diff()`. This function will calculate differences between two consecutive numbers of vectors.

```
 set.seed(1)
 x<-sample(1:10,10)
 x
 [1]  3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6 10  1
 diff(x)
[1]  1  1  2 -5  6  1 -3  4 -9
```

Answer (score 2):

To do your original problem of diffing 1st and 2nd, 3rd and 4th, I'd transform the data into a matrix and do diffs along columns.

```
set.seed(1)
x=sample(1:10,10)
x
 [1]  3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6 10  1
```

So our answer is going to be -1, -2, -6, 3, 9 from (3-4), (5-7), (2-8), (9-6) and (10-1).

This makes our matrix:

```
> matrix(x,nrow=2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    5    2    9   10
[2,]    4    7    8    6    1
```

and then we apply `diff` to columns, adding a negative sign because `diff` does subtraction the other way round:

```
> -apply(matrix(x,nrow=2),2,diff)
[1] -1 -2 -6  3  9
```